# Tool for generating C# classes from NHibernate mappings files?

Tags: nhibernate

What tool is there for generating C# classes from NHibernate mappings files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the [NHibernate resources page](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#toolsetguide-s2) under 'Helpful tools', there are a few code generators listed:
[http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#toolsetguide-s2)

Answer (score 1):

[NConstruct Lite](http://www.nconstruct.com/App/NConstructLite.aspx?PageId=12) generate both mapping files and C# classes - all data is read from a database (MS SQL, Oracle, Access).

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a small one : http://www.codeplex.com/EntityGenerator

Currently it's a small console application with a configuration file. Not very user friendly but it works and the templates are easily customizable.

Still under heavy development, I'll update it when I have some time :)